# Counting subsets of different sizes of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ be a non-empty set, and $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ denote the power set of $A$ excluding empty set. There is a natural equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$:

> for $S_1,S_2\in \mathcal{P}^*(A)$ (i.e. $S_1,S_2\subseteq A$), we say $S_1\sim S_2$ if there is a bijection between $S_1,S_2$.

The question I am concerning here is about *the number* of equivalence classes of $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ under $\sim$. When $A$ is a finite set, then the number of equivalence classes is easily seen to be $|A|$; this can also be proved if $A$ is countable, by providing a bijection between $A$ and the equivalence classes of $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$.

**Question:** What is the number of equivalence classes of $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ under $\sim$ if $A$ is uncountably infinite?

The number of equivalence classes in $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ is intuitively seems to be $|A|$, but I am not getting any direction in case $A$ is uncountably infinite. I didn't find such thing (question/fact) in some standard texts of set theory.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for leaving out the empty set?  Your equivalence relation works just as well if you include it (there's just one more equivalence class).

Comment: Suppose $|A|=10$. Then the number of equivalence classes in $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ is $10$, while including empty set will give $11$. Just for this reason, I dropped empty set, and tried to see how can we obtain a bijection in general (which is not always possible, from answers below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what $A$ is.  In fact, (assuming the axiom of choice) the number of equivalence classes of $\mathcal{P}^*(A)$ for $A$ uncountable can be any infinite cardinality at all, by choosing $A$ appropriately.  By definition, if $|A|=\aleph_{\alpha}$, the infinite cardinals that are less than or equal to $|A|$ exactly the cardinals $\aleph_\beta$ for $\beta\leq\alpha$.  So the number of different cardinalities of subsets of $A$ is $\aleph_0+|\alpha|$.  Here $\alpha$ can be any ordinal at all, so $|\alpha|$ can be any cardinal.

Note that in particular, for instance, ZFC cannot answer this question for $A=\mathbb{R}$, since ZFC cannot determine which aleph number $|\mathbb{R}|$ is (it cannot even determine the cardinality of the ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\aleph_\alpha=|\mathbb{R}|$; all that can really be said is that $|\alpha|\leq|\mathbb{R}|$).

Comment: Actually for any successor ordinal $\alpha$ less than $|\mathbb R|.$ Not that this solves anything because ZFC can't determine what the upper bound  (for $\alpha$) that $ |\mathbb R|$ is.

Comment: Right, my statement is a bit imprecise.  A more precise statement would be that given a model of set theory and any successor ordinal $\alpha$ in that model, there is a forcing extension in which $|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_\alpha$.

Answer (score 4):

If $|A|=\omega_\alpha$, there are $\omega+|\alpha|$ cardinal numbers less than or equal $|A|$ and hence $\omega+|\alpha|$ equivalence classes under $\sim$. Thus, the answer is $\max\{\omega,|\alpha|\}$. (I am assuming the axiom of choice here, as otherwise matters get *really* messy.)